# FloodWaitError on GetParticipants out of nowhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

Hello there I'm trying to scrap members but I'm facing this issue :

```
[+] Choose a group to scrape members :

[0] - Hotbit Pump

[1] - FAST PUMP

[+] Enter a Number : 0

[+] Fetching Members...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 81, in <module>
    all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)
  File "C:\Users\A7moo7y\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\telethon\sync.py", line 39, in syncified
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "C:\Users\A7moo7y\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 579, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\A7moo7y\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\chats.py", line 507, in get_participants
    return await self.iter_participants(*args, **kwargs).collect()
  File "C:\Users\A7moo7y\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\telethon\requestiter.py", line 113, in collect
    async for message in self:
  File "C:\Users\A7moo7y\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\telethon\requestiter.py", line 74, in __anext__
    if await self._load_next_chunk():
  File "C:\Users\A7moo7y\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\chats.py", line 222, in _load_next_chunk
    results = await self.client(self.requests)
  File "C:\Users\A7moo7y\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "C:\Users\A7moo7y\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 80, in _call
    raise MultiError(exceptions, results, requests)
telethon.errors.common.MultiError: ([None, None, FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), None, FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 27 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)')], [<telethon.tl.types.channels.ChannelParticipants object at 0x00000216D7091588>, <telethon.tl.types.channels.ChannelParticipants object at 0x00000216D6F21948>, None, None, None, <telethon.tl.types.channels.ChannelParticipants object at 0x00000216D6DFC3C8>, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [<telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D26848>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D268C8>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D26948>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D269C8>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D26A48>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D26AC8>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D26B48>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D26BC8>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D26C48>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D26CC8>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D26D48>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D26DC8>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D26E48>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D26EC8>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D26F48>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D26FC8>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D2A088>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D2A108>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D2A188>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D2A208>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D2A288>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D2A308>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D2A388>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D2A408>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D2A488>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x00000216D6D2A508>])
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

use False condition

```
all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

`aggressive=False` doesn't work when members are too many in the group, possible error reported `error, ChannelParticipants object is not subscriptible`.

FIX: for telethon i made a little modification i turned aggressive to `false` and edited the file `Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\chats.py` in line 222

Before

```
    results = await self.client(self.requests)
    for i in reversed(range(len(self.requests))):
        participants = results[i]
```

After

```
    results = await self.client(self.requests)
    for i in reversed(range(len(self.requests))):
        if isinstance(results, list):
            participants = results[i]
        else:
            participants = results
```

*last check 25/06/2022*